# Disable Tap Gesture on Child View Controller? How to determine Is it a PanGesture or TapGesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

All.

In my iOS 8.0 app.

In a Parent Child View architecture. By this code...

```
[self addChildViewController:slideTableViewController];
[self.view addSubview:slideTableViewController.view];
[slideTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

**I have implemented TapGesturerecognizer & PanGesturerecognizer on Base View Controller.**

So, that it can recognise Pan(Dragging) and Tap. I need both gestures on my BaseView.

**Just do not want Tap Gesture on** `SlideView`.
As I want to execute didSelectRowAtIndexpath method on child view,

**Solution:**

**Answer for Question 1:**
Many StackOverflow answers have the same funda..
Disable Tap gesture when your touch encounters child view.

```
if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){
                if(CGRectContainsPoint(slideTableViewController.view.frame,[touch locationInView:self.view])){
                    return NO;
     }
}
```

**Answer for Question 2:**

How to determine Is it a PanGesture or TapGesture ?

For **each** gesture type the delegate method will call

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

If you have implemented two gestures in your view, pan gesture and touch gesture,

**This method will call 2 times, 1 time for pan gesture and 1 time for tap gesture.**

So, in this method you can check like `isKindOfClass` method.

Thank you very much for helping......

[image]

Comment: Why not set `gesture.enabled = NO`

Comment: @Bannings Its better to use ```userInterationEnabled``` property.

Comment: could you post the code of how you are adding the gesture recognizer? maybe you are adding it to the wrong view

Comment: I am adding the Gesture Recognizer by Storyboarding.

Comment: @ArpitParekh Just check `[gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]`

Comment: Ya It is the only solution, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the gesture's delegate method in your `baseViewController` :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizershouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return touch.view == self.view;
}
```

OR
**//If it is a Tap Gesture and Your touch intersects with a perticular View, For that we have this method.**

```
if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){
                if(CGRectContainsPoint(slideTableViewController.view.frame,[touch locationInView:self.view])){
                    return NO;
     }
}
```

Comment: It always return YES. Ya but I think we are near to the answer.

Comment: Somewhere I have checked that locationInView method of touches will work...but worrying about implementing it...

Comment: You want to the tap gesture to be recognized only on baseViewController, right? I think that `locationInView` method not suitable here. The `touch.view` should return a top-view. Did you touch on the `baseViewController`'s view or  the `childViewController`'s view?

Comment: I touch on both view controllers, touch.view always gives the top view as you mentioned.

Comment: Did you check the view's frame of the childViewController?

Comment: Ya...let me post the image.

Comment: Is the view's frame of the `childViewController` out of bounds of its superview?

Comment: Initially I was hiding it, to the left of baseViewController afterwords It takes place in BaseViewController, Just frames are setted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81945/discussion-between-bannings-and-arpit-parekh).

Answer (score 5):

Just set `tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in UIViews I hope this could help you:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
[touch locationInView:self.view];
if(touch.view == self.topView )
{
     //just return
}
if(touch.view == SOSTopView )
{
   //just return
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, Sorry but touchesBeganMethod will not been called when gesture recogniser is enabled. because I have set "tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES"....

Comment: You have added single tap or multiple ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should implement this method of `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // you can add some logic here
    return nil;
}
```

This will prevent from selecting any rows.

Comment: No, I have not used this method. Fyi I am using Static cells  ? will it affect any behavious of TableViewDiDselect method.

Comment: See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)

Answer (score -1):

Isn't there a `userInteractionEnabled` property that you can make use of? So you could do the following:

```
slideTableViewController.userInterationEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: I want to use the TableViewController didSelectMethod.